# java - is that possible to develop GPS software on PC

Tags: java, gps

i want to make an application for tablet PC / notebook i want to make software to acquire a location(longitude and latitude)for PC.
is that possible for me to develop GPS for PC with java programming language???
if yes, what software i need to download to develop that application????

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific around what you mean by "every PC that logged in".

Comment: Barring the use of an onboard, GPS (or related) device (to which you have access), the only way to get this sort of information is from _user input_ addresses.  Most ISPs assign IP addresses dynamically to average consumers - and in order to _get_ that information, it usually requires a court order.  Some tablets and phones use WiFi signals to get a (usuable) estimate, but your target audience may not be around enough recognized data-points to discover this.  Using WiFi in this manner would be dependent on whether the component is installed and active.

Comment: thanks x zero. thats good explaination for me, :D

Comment: so that mean the only way to develop it is with wifi . i see it.. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

First of all, you'll need a GPS receiver (either built into the computer, or connected to it).

Typically, GPS units use a [simple text protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) to talk to the host over the serial port. There are plenty of libraries out there that can help you if you don't want to parse the protocol yourself; just google "gps java".

Lastly, bear in mind that typically GPS units don't work indoors since they require an unobstructed view of the sky.

Comment: thanks aix, i dont know about simple text protocol before. thanks for information :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have at least a GPS device to receive the GPS information! Usually, devices are connected through USB, serial port, or Bluetooth. Interface with the device (read the manufacturer's reference book on that). Once you start getting the information, all you have to do is to parse the data and adopt to your program accordingly!